# Unable to set a null value when manipulating xml

Tags: karate

I have the following xml:

```
<Company>
  <Section>ABC</Section>
</Company>
```

I am conducting a negative test of sorts and want to send a NULL value to the "Section" element of the xml.

I tried the following:

```
* set xml /Company/Section = (null)

However, what happens is that the opening tag of the element gets deleted altogether resulting in:

<Company>
  </Section>
</Company>

Expected result should be:
<Company>
  <Section></Section>
</Company>
```

I would've liked to try .replace but the value inside "Section" is dynamic and so I cannot effectively use .replace. I also tried an empty string ('') and the same behavior happens where the opening tag gets deleted.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what a `null` should do.

If an empty string does not work, that is a big surprise to me. Then the best option is [you submit an issue](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue) and ideally contribute a PR to fix it also. Else consider what you ask for as not supported.

Comment: Thank you for your response @Peter Thomas. I was under the impression that Karate treats null and (null) differently. I have used (null) before when manipulating JSON objects and it basically sends an empty value (vs deleting the key). However, this doesn't seem to be the case with xml. Single string indeed acts the same way. I will submit an issue.